# Sitecore 6.4 + Lucene - Template inheritance

Tags: templates, inheritance, lucene, sitecore

After a few hours of figuring out Lucene, I gave up. Hope you can help.

**Setting**

In our current Sitecore tree, we have template 2 template inheritance levels. (Let's say Vehicle -> Car -> Formula One / Vehicle -> Boat).

What I would need to fetch through Lucene now, is every ContentItem inheritting *either directly*, or *indirectly*, from a certain Template.

For instance:

- Get vehicles -> **returns:** "Generic" Vehicles, Cars, F1 Cars and boats
- Get cars -> **returns:** Cars, F1 Cars

What I thought was using the `_templates`-field in Lucene, ie:
Get Vehicles -> `_templates` contains Vehicle-template-guid.
Get Cars -> `_templates` contains Car-template-guid.

**The problem**

The main problem I experience is that Content Items of the *F1 Car*-template contain **only** the Cars and F1 Car in the `_templates`-field, and **not** the generic "Vehicle".

I probably misinterpret the _templates-field,  but am wondering if there's any other options.

---

**Sitecore configuration:**

Content items:

- sitecore

  - content

    - Home

      - **ACategory**

        - A Child 1
        - A Child 1.1
        - A Child 2

Templates (levels = inheritance):

- **Main entity**

  - *Child entity 1*

    - Child entity 1.1
  - *Child entity 2*
- **Category**

Comment: What Lucene approach are you taking? The "old" Lucene approach or the "new" one? Are you using the [Advanced Database Crawler](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/11/sitecore-searcher-and-advanced-database.html)?

Comment: We're working on a custom index, maintained by a custom crawler inheriting Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler. This crawler adds a few of our custom fields to the item as well. - Currently, the solution I'm trying is writing item.Template.ID.Guid and (recursively) each baseTemplate.Guid to a new field. I think this would work (it's pretty similar as the _path-field, only for template inheritance instead), I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an new indexer which inherits Sitecore.Data.Indexing.Index, and override the AddFields method as below:

```
protected override void AddFields(Item item, Document document)
{   
    // Add base fields
    base.AddFields(item, document);

    // Add all inherited templates id to a field 
    string TEMPLATE-PATH="get template path for this item here";
    document.Add(new Field("template-path", TEMPLATE-PATH, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.TOKENIZED)); 
}
```

Then you can search it by "template-path" field.

Comment: As mentioned @ original post's comments, I'm using the new Sitecore Lucene approach. What you mention is, however, similar to how I solved the thing: added a new field including the entire template hierarchy. Thanks Mark and chiesa, going to mark this one as answer.

Comment: What I mean is , not new crawler but a new indexer. 
In the config, you can edit the index as below,

 <index id="yourIndexName" singleInstance="true" type="YourIndexClass, Yourdll">